# Postprocessing with Sklearn in Tensorflow Serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensorflow-serving

I developed a classificator using Tensorflow. The class labels are One-Hot Encoded using

```py
sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
```

Wrapping the whole application into a Flask-App worked totally fine, but due to company architecture, the application should be deployed with tensorflow serving. Now I need to integrate the postprocessing (and thus the sklearn `labelBinarizer` object into the graph). What is the best way to do this?

I saw that it would be possible to write a custom inference method, something like this

```py
lbl_binarizer = load_lbl_bin()

@tf.function
def inference(param1, param2):
    prediction = model.predict(param1,param2)
    return lbl_binarizer.inverse_transform(prediction)
```

Afterwars this function can be also stored with the model, using the `signature` param inside the `model.save()` method. But how can I inject the `lbl_binarizer` object and the model into this function?

Comment: Are the labels sparse? because if not then you can altogether replace the `LabelBinarizer`

Comment: They are a 5 digit number which aren't numerated. I am not sure if you could consider this sparse